# Scrape latitude and longitude (Google Maps) inside <Script type="text/javascript"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I'm beginner in Web Scrapping. I'm trying to get latitude and longitude from this web:

https://urbania.pe/inmueble/proyecto/ememhvin-proyecto-mariscal-castilla-lima-santiago-de-surco-tale-inmobiliaria-65659522

A part containing such data is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ==$0
    const POSTING = {{[...] 
    "locationId":"V1-B-4368","name":"Lima","label":"PROVINCIA","depth":1,"parent":{"locationId":"V1-A-111","name":"Peru urbania","label":"PAIS","depth":0,"parent":null,"acronym":null},"acronym":null},"acronym":null},"acronym":null},"postingGeolocation":{"geolocation":{"latitude":-12.133920500000000,"longitude":-77.014942900000000},
    [...]

<script>
```

I'm trying to do, but not works:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.parse

sa_key = 'ea69223fa47f72fac0907759' # TOKEN from a web 
sa_api = 'https://api.scrapingant.com/v2/general'

page='https://urbania.pe/inmueble/proyecto/ememhvin-proyecto-mariscal-castilla-lima-santiago-de-surco-tale-inmobiliaria-65659522'

qParams = {'url':page , 'x-api-key': sa_key}  #OJO: aqui tener cuidado con /proyecto/ y /clasificado/  , estructura para 1°
reqUrl = f'{sa_api}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(qParams)}'  

r = requests.get(reqUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

list_geolocalization=[]

# trying to get latitude and lingitude
geolocalization=soup.find_all('script',{'type': 'text/javascript'})

for tag in geolocalization:
    list_geolocalization.append(tag.find('latitude'))
    df_geolocalization=pd.DataFrame(list_geolocalization,columns = ["geolocalization"])

#other
lat, long=re.findall(r'(?is)("latitude":|"longitude":)([0-9.]+)',geolocalization)
```

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your link is correct? There's none of the snippet you shared in the soup of your link. Maybe updating your post with you full code (including url requesting) can be very helpful.

Comment: Link is correct my friend, only part of the html is displayed. My code for scraping latitude and longitude doesn't works.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting a 403 status code as the site is protected by CloudFlare?

Comment: yes, you are right. Now I put my complete code.

Comment: [undetected_chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) is the surefire option when it comes to fetching data from Cloudflare-protected sites.

Comment: oh, you should install Chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. There is a youtube video that explain how install and other things:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57ukgFoHSy0&ab_channel=FileTech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, You can take advantages of Regular Expression as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "https://urbania.pe/inmueble/proyecto/ememhvin-proyecto-mariscal-castilla-lima-santiago-de-surco-tale-inmobiliaria-65659522"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(response)
r = re.search(r'const POSTING = {.*}',str(soup))
if r:
    j = json.loads(r.group(0).replace('const POSTING = ', ''))
    lat = j.get('postingLocation', {}).get('postingGeolocation', {}).get('geolocation', {}).get('latitude')
    print(lat)
    long = j.get('postingLocation', {}).get('postingGeolocation', {}).get('geolocation', {}).get('longitude')
    print(long)
else:
    print("No match found.")
```

**Outout:**

```
-12.1339205
-77.0149429
```

Comment: Thanks!! Regular Expressions are very useful.